# How to reuse a custom pyramid json renderer from inside a called __json__ or adapter?

Tags: python, json, pyramid

Using pyramid, I have a hierarchy of objects I want to dump as json.

Some of these objects are not out of the box json serializable so I either implement **json** or have adapter's registered to a custom json_renderer that I have registered(so I don't need to monkey patch things like datetime).

Since they are nested(e.g there's a datetime further down that hierarchy) I can't just call up json.dumps within my classes **json** since it's not aware of the adapters.

I've tried to read through the source, and run this through the debugger and feel like I could go and pull the renderer from the registry and fiddle about with that? But I don't think that is the intended method. Surely there is something cleaner? Unfortunately all the examples in the docs are trivial.

How can I pass back serialization to the calling custom json renderer at json_dump_using_renderer()?

```
def custom_json_renderer():    
    def datetime_adapter(obj, request):
        return obj.isoformat()
    json_renderer = JSON()
    json_renderer.add_adapter(datetime.datetime, datetime_adapter)

class Whatever(object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

    def __json__(self):
        return "{ item: " + json_dump_using_renderer(obj.items) + "}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for starters your `__json__` method should take `(self, request)` not just `(self)`.. From there, you can use `pyramid.renderers.render` to perform a manual rendering if you want to embed a json-encoded string inside another data structure. Note that this will end up causing the item to be double-encoded but hopefully you're aware of that already.

```
def __json__(self, request):
    return {'item': pyramid.renderers.render('json', obj.items, request=request)}
```

Alternatively if you don't want the data to be double-encoded then you might just be asking why the adapters do not work on sub-items of an object returned from `__json__` and the answer is that the adapters are implemented using the `default` argument of `json.dumps` and it just doesn't support what you want. You'd have to find a json serialization library that does... but I'm not aware of one.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the __json__ method could also be passed the request, thanks.